# Регулярное выражение, подтверждающее, что слово встречается ровно 2 раза

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня есть каша из текста из символов. Как пример:

```
3242ваывдл3r3map235map4346{
```

Мне нужно написать такую регулярку, которая будет проверять что слово map в этой каше встречается ровно два раза. Не больше и не меньше. Каша вокруг слов map безразмерная и может содержать любое количество символов и пробелов, кроме, разумеется, самого слова map.

Comment: Если у вас есть доступ к коду, лучше всего найти все вхождения и проверить их количество. Например, в Python: `bool(text.count('map') == 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
^((?!map).)*map((?!map).)*map((?!map).)*$
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/xEvY9c/2

```
3242ваывдл3r3map235map4346{
3242ваывдл3r3map235map434map6{
3242ваывдл3r3ma235map4346{
mapmap
map
map  map m a p 123
```

Comment: У меня немного покороче из-за `{2}`, а так вроде одинаково :)

Comment: Ну вот не видать мне плюсов :(

Comment: У меня не сработало. Хотелось бы дополнить, что между мапами есть куча пробелов/отступов, помимо символов. Может быть это помешало...

Comment: @ТимофейПанфилий переносы строки не входят в `.` по-умолчанию, если вы об этом. Попробуйте поставить `(?s)`. Я привёл используемые тесты, добавьте по ссылке тот, который не работает (добавил с пробелами тест)

Comment: @dIm0n
https://regex101.com/r/JiB3l0/1/
совсем не хочет

Comment: @ТимофейПанфилий флаг `s` поставьте там справа https://regex101.com/r/JiB3l0/2

Comment: @dIm0n если добавить в любое место еще раз ключевое слово, то он все равно заматчится

Comment: @ТимофейПанфилий вы не поставили ^ и $ https://regex101.com/r/JiB3l0/3

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Answer (score 4):

```
^(((?!map).)*map){2}((?!map).)*$
```

```css
input { outline: none !important; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; }
:valid { border: 1px solid green; }
:invalid { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<input autofocus pattern="^(((?!map).)*map){2}((?!map).)*$" required value="3242ваывдл3r3map235map4346">
```

Comment: Это тоже у меня не сработало. Хотелось бы дополнить, что между мапами есть куча пробелов/отступов, помимо символов. Может быть это помешало...

Comment: @ТимофейПанфилий, у меня работает. Поиграйся с точкой.

Answer (score 1):

**update в конце ответа**
Хоть правильный ответ уже дан, я тоже поучаствую:

```
(?=(?:.*(map)){2})(?!(?:.*\1){3}).*
```

Ключи ставить нужно захватывая новую строку, обычно это single line **s**

Схема работы проста:
`.*` - любое количество любых символов
`(?=(?:.*(map)){2})` - проверяем что повторяется необходимая нам последовательность 2 раза
`(?!(?:.*\1){3})` - проверяем что наше совпадение не встречается трижды, увеличивать квантификацию раскрыв диапазон в принципе лишняя трата системного времени.

---

Из плюсов вижу только то что менять слово-шаблон нужно в одном месте и немного меньше план подбора выходит, но не сильно.

---

**upd:** Кстати, есть смысл добавить в шаблон границу слова `\b`
`(?=(?:.*\b(map)\b){2})(?!(?:.*\b\1\b){3}).*` исключив при этом *maptext*,*textmap* и *textmaptext* оставив только полное совпадение